# Returning the location of an element in 2D array recursively

Tags: java, recursion

The code I have written for this method so far is:

```
int rowCount = 0;
int columnCount = 0;
Pair p = new Pair(0, 0);
public Pair search2D(int[][] data, int element) {
     if(data[rowCount].length==columnCount)
        {
            rowCount++;
            columnCount=0;
        }

        if(data.length > rowCount)
        {
            if(data[rowCount][columnCount] == element)
            {
                p = new Pair(rowCount, columnCount);
            }
            else
            {
                columnCount++;
                search2D(data, element);
            }
        }
        return p;
}
```

"Pair" is a class I wrote because Java only allows me to return a single number, and I'm trying to return the indices that hold the location of the element.

In my main method, I have

```
    int[][] table = new int[][] { {3, 2, 8}, {3, 5, 6} };
    System.out.println(r.search2D(table, 5));
    System.out.println(r.search2D(table, 8));
```

However, both of the outputs are (1, 1). I'm told not to use any loops, could anyone point me in the right direction or tell me where the issue is?

Comment: @FallAndLearn not getting an error, but the location of 8 in the table is not (1, 1).

Comment: Where are rowcount and columncount initialized ?

Comment: In the method rowCount and columnCount are not defined, where are they?

Comment: @FallAndLearn @Matthew right before the method tag I have `int rowCount = 0;
 int columnCount = 0;
 Pair p = new Pair(0, 0);`

Comment: You need to place `rowCount`, `columnCount`, and `Pair p` inside the method so they are set back to default before the search. After you did the first search for example, `rowCount` will still be equal to 1.

Comment: @Matthew are they initialized to 0 like I have them before the method? When I do place them in the method and initialize them to 0, I get a lot of stackoverflow errors

Answer (score 2):

After you find `r.search2D(table, 5)` you are not resetting the values of `rowcount` and `columncount`.  Hence for `r.search2D(table, 8)` also you are getting answer as 1,1.

To overcome this problem modify the function as:

```
public Pair search2D(int[][] data, int element, int rowcount, int columncount){}
```

and call as `search2D(data,element,0,0);`

Comment: This is the cleanest solution.

Comment: Clearest and does not do the homework. Another tip is to use the return value of the recursive call, to stop/continue searching. And I would rename *Count into *Index or *Subscript.

Comment: @FallAndLearn After making these changes, I'm getting stack overflow errors in my method on the line search2D(data,element,0,0);

Comment: Your code is incomplete. You have to put the base,end, boundary conditions for recursion to perform properly so that you do no get any stackoverflow, indexoutofbound exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that I think should do the trick. It is normally better design not to rely on global variables.

```
public Pair search2D(int[][] data, int element) {
    return search2D(0, 0, data, element);
}

public Pair search2D(int i, int j, int[][] data, int element) {
    if (i == data.length) {
        return new Pair(-1, -1);
    }
    if (j == data[i].length) {
        return search2D(i + 1, 0, data, element);
    }
    if (data[i][j] == element) {
        return new Pair(i, j);
    }
    return search2D(i, j + 1, data, element);
}
```

**Update:** I see now that this might not be the help you needed. You wanted help to get your code to work. But use this as alternative implementation, it shows some  of the powers of recursion. :)

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't considering the recursion part of it but rowCount and columnCount are not reset after your first search and you should change your method so that they are both 0 at the beginning.

```
public Pair search2D(int[][] data, int element) {
    return search2D(data, element, 0, 0);
}

public Pair search2D(int[][] data, int element, int rowCount, int columnCount) {
    //your method
}
```

Also, the way without recursion may be easier.

```
public Pair search2D(int[][] data, int element) {
    for(int row = 0; row < int.length; row++)
        for(int col = 0; col < int[].length; col++)
            if(data[row][col] == element) return new Pair(row, col);
    return new Pair(-1, -1);
}
```

Comment: This is what my answer says. What is the need of adding two same answers